# C# interface inheritance (can inherit how many other interfaces)

Tags: c#, interface

I understand that

```
a class can inherit multiple interfaces and

a abstract class can inherit from another class  and one or more interfaces
```

How bout interface inheritance,

Can an interface inherit from multiple interfaces?

Comment: Yes it can. From any number. Give it a try!

Comment: Yes you could. actually you could this these out very quickly.

Comment: Isn't creating a few classes and testing it directly faster than asking on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. Look at [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 1):

An `interface` is not *inherited* it is *implemented*, so it is not involved in the 'single inheritence' rule.  Anything that can implement an `interface` can implement *multiple* interfaces.

The slightly confusing thing - and the answer to your question - is that an interface can implement other interfaces.  Effectively the interface *inherits* all of the characteristics of every interface it implements:

```
interface IHasPosition
{
    float X { get; }
    float Y { get; }
}

interface IHasValue<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

interface IPositionValue<T> : IHasPosition, IHasValue<T>
{ }
```

Rather than being simply an empty interface, `IPositionValue<T>` has all three properties from the two interfaces it implements.  When creating a class that implements `IPositionValue<T>`, the class automatically implements the interfaces that `IPositionValue<T>` implements:

```
class StringAtLocation : IPositionValue<string>
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    StringAtLocation foo = new StringAtLocation { X = 0, Y = 0, Value = "foo" };
    // All of the following are valid because of interface inheritence:
    IHasPosition ihp = foo;
    IHasValue<string> ihv = foo;
    IPositionValue<string> ipv = foo;       
}
```

And no, it's not documented in the [`interface` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) documentation or the [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) section on MSDN.  Sadly.